# Adding explanation next to the successive equations in latex

Tags: equations, align

How can I add such descriptions next to the successive aligned equations using LaTeX?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX:SE! What you tray?

Answer (score 10):

I think it's better to use an `alignat` or `alignat*` environment rather than an `array` environment to display several rows of equations, for two reasons. First, the rows are spaced slightly farther apart than if an `array` environment is used. Second, the material is typeset in display-style math mode by default -- which is appropriate for displayed equations.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'alignat*' env.
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % Times Roman text and math fonts

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
A+(B+C) 
  &= [a_{ij}]+[b_{ij}+c_{ij}] &\qquad& \text{by Definition 1.29} \\
  &= [a_{ij}+(b_{ij}+c_{ij})] && \text{by Definition 1.29} \\
  &= [(a_{ij}+b_{ij})+c_{ij}] && \text{since addition in $\mathbf{R}$ is associative} \\
  &= [a_{ij}+b_{ij}]+[c_{ij}] && \text{by Definition 1.29} \\
  &= (A+B)+C
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a possibility:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
The following equalities establish the associative property for addition.
\[\begin{array}{r @{} >{{}}c<{{}} @{} ll}
    A+(B+C)&=&[a_{ij}]+[b_{ij}+c_{ij}]&\mbox{By definition 1.29}\\
           &=&[a_{ij}+(b_{ij}+c_{ij})]&\mbox{By definition 1.29}\\
           &=&[(a_{ij}+b_{ij})+c_{ij}]&\mbox{since addition in $\mathbf R$ is associative}\\
           &=&[a_{ij}+b_{ij}]+[c_{ij}]&\mbox{By definition 1.29}\\
           &=&(A+B)+C&\mbox{By definition 1.29}
  \end{array}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

With `{WithArrows}` of the package `witharrows`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for \MoveEqLeft
\usepackage{witharrows}

\begin{document}
The following equalities establish the associative property for addition.

$\begin{WithArrows}
    \MoveEqLeft{A+(B+C)} \Arrow{By definition 1.29} \\
           &=\left[a_{ij}\right]+\left[b_{ij}+c_{ij}\right] \Arrow{By definition 1.29}\\
           &=\left[a_{ij}+\left(b_{ij}+c_{ij}\right)\right] \Arrow{since addition in $\mathbf R$ is associative}\\
           &=\left[\left(a_{ij}+b_{ij}\right)+c_{ij}\right] \Arrow{By definition 1.29}\\
           &=\left[a_{ij}+b_{ij}\right]+\left[c_{ij}\right] \Arrow{By definition 1.29} \\
           &=(A+B)+C
\end{WithArrows}$
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 3):

As starting point is considered @José Carlos Santos answer (+1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
The following equalities establish the associative property for addition.
\[\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
    \begin{array}{r@{\,}c@{\,}l >{\qquad$}l<{$}}
A+(B+C) &=& [a_{ij}] + [b_{ij} + c_{ij}]    & by definition 1.29    \\
        &=& [a_{ij}+ (b_{ij} + c_{ij})]     & by definition 1.29    \\
        &=& [(a_{ij}+b_{ij}) + c_{ij}]      & since addition in $\mathbf{R}$ is associative\\
        &=& [a_{ij}+b_{ij}]  + [c_{ij}]     & by definition 1.29    \\
        &=& (A+B)+C                         & by definition 1.29 
  \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]